# How to put more than one class in css not() selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to stack more than one class in `not()` selector but `,;:` does not work.

```
input[type=text]:hover:not(.ui-pg-input .mandatory){ background-color: #D9EDF7;}
```

So, what is proper way to stack classes in css `not()` selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two syntactic alternatives:

1. use two classes in one `:not` operator:

`input[type=text]:hover:not(.ui-pg-input.mandatory){background-color: #D9EDF7;}`

*(note the removed blank between the classes)*

2. use the `:not` operator twice:

`input[type=text]:hover:not(.ui-pg-input):not(.mandatory){background-color: #D9EDF7;}`

Note however that both have different meaning: the first uses an *or* operator, so it matches all elements not having both classes (so having none or one), whilst the second uses an *and* operator, thus matching all elements not having one or the other class (so having none). So it depends on what you want to do...

Comment: a note - I don't think #1 works, even though it seems like it should. I am still trying to figure out how to do exactly what this answer suggests #1 does (apply a rule if element has neither class a nor class b, or only one of them, but not both), See here for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9jhu0qc5/1/ - if this worked you would expect the first 2 boxes to have a black border, but not so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two`not()` to do this example:

`p:not(.class_one):not(.class_two){`

```css
p:not(.one):not(.two){
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<p class="one">Text</p>
<p class="two">Text</p>
<p class="three">Text</p>
```